# IIS and MVC routing problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a little problem when i try to deoploy my mvc app over IIS.

my app on localhost gives me no problem (`http://local:8080/` for instance), but when deploy to iis the new route is `http://domain.com/preventa/` so this route configuration breaks all my javascript and css routes..

how can i fix that  without modifying my js's and css's?

thanks

**Update.**

here is a snipet of js function.

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/proyecto/FechaServidor',
            data: "",
```

this dosent work... the request url of this is

```
http://domain.com/preventa/proyecto/index/proyecto/FechaServidor...
```

because this, i need to put `../../proyecto/FechaServidor` on the JS and the url shoud be.

```
   http://domain.com/preventa/proyecto/FechaServidor...
```

Comment: Show how you are loading your `.css` and `.js` files

Comment: Are you sure you actually have the leading forward slash? The url you are getting suggests your have `url: 'proyecto/FechaServidor'`

Comment: i think i maybe be wrong.... but look this other example.

               `"processing": true,               
                "sAjaxSource": "/home/ListarProyectosAsignados?usuarioid=" + usuarioID,`

the request url is:

`http://domain.com/home/ListarProyectosAsignados`

and should be 

`http://domain.com/preventa/home/ListarProyectosAsignados`

Comment: No, the url is correct. Perpending the forward slash means relative to the domain. Omitting the forward slash means relative to the current request.

Comment: this is not the point my friend

Comment: Yes it is. If you want `http://domain.com/preventa/home/ListarProyectosAsignados` then the url needs to be "/preventa/home/ListarProyectosAsignados".

Comment: i dont want to change the path in JS.. i think that change every time the path before build and publish my app is not the best idea

Comment: That's why its considered best practice to construct urls with the `@Url.Action()` helpers - so you don't get these problems.

Comment: i think the same, but how can i use @url.action inside of .js file?

Comment: If its a separate file, then you cant directly use it. What you do is have the javascript method accept a parameter and use the `@Url.Action()` in the main view. For example, in main view (assuming you wanted to navigate to the `Index` page of the `HomeController` in the `Admin` area) `var url='@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "Admin" });`, then pass this value to the function in the external `.js` file.